# List of vector to one raster in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, raster-conversion, union, alignment

I need to rasterize a part of OSM map by coordinates. I found rather good algorithm, but can’t finish it. I have problems in STEP 3.

I described all algorithm here – may be someone have the same task.

**STEP 1:**
Create a polygon (box polygon) with cover of wanted part of map.

Function (or query):

```
INSERT INTO rast.box (box_geom) 
VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((30.200 59.920, 30.200 59.960, 30.260 59.960, 30.260 59.920, 30.200 59.920))',4326));
```

Order of creating points (corners coordinates): lowLeft->upperLeft->upperRight->lowRight->lowLeft. 5 points.

**STEP 2:** 
Use ST_Overlaps and ST_Within to choose geometry objects inside box polygon. In my example -  polygons of buildings.
My Function:

```
INSERT INTO rast.over
SELECT g.geom 
FROM rast.spb g, rast.box b
WHERE ST_Overlaps (g.geom, b. box_geom)=true 
OR 
ST_Within (g.geom, b. box_geom)=true 
AND 
b.id=1;
```

b.id is id of box polygon.

**STEP 3:** Use ST_AsRaster and ST_Union for rasterization all of objects and union in one.
I found posts about this theme (http://geospatialelucubrations.blogspot.ca/2014/05/a-guide-to-rasterization-of-vector.html, and this one is good too: postgis.17.x6.nabble.com/Rasterize-a-vector-td4997893, sorry I can post only 2 links), but I don’t understand some things:

**Substep 3.1:**    In first guide, the author used two tables – first named “forestcover”, second named “elevation”, but I have only one table with OSM geometries.
When he used ST_AsRaster, he used the second parameter:  raster ref (from http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_AsRaster.html). 
**Could you explain how can I use it?**

**Substep 3.2:**
    My function:

```
CREATE TABLE rast.result  AS
SELECT ST_AsRaster(q, 100, 100, '4BUI')
FROM rast.over;
```

When I’m trying only to rasterize (without union) – it’s working. The table with special column is created. And I also find the result table with rows (I have 1700 geometry objects and I have 1700 rows with raster  type ). 
**But the rows are empty! Why?** 
I try to look from pgAdmin3.
And when I try to see this raster table in QGIS2.4 (through DB Manager), I have this Error:

> “Error, the table rast.airports contains tiles with different srid.
>   This feature is not yet supported by the PostGIS Raster driver.
>   Please, specify a table that contains only tiles with the same srid or
>   provide a 'where' constraint to select just the tiles with the same
>   value for srid”

I checked table in ST_SRID and all of rows are in the same srid (in 4326).

**Substep 3.3:**
    When I try to union the raster from the result table or from this function:

```
CREATE TABLE rast.result AS
SELECT 
ST_Union(ST_AsRaster(q, 100, 100, '4BUI'))
FROM rast.over;
```

I have this Error in pgAdmin sql-console:

> rt_raster_from_two_rasters: The two rasters provided do not have the
>   same alignment

**May be the problem is with “alignment”? How can I fix it?**

**STEP 4:** My last step should be to convert postgis raster to GEOtiff. And I’m going to use ST_AsTiff.

Please, help to solve these problems!

Answer (score 1):

Substep 3.1: The reference raster is used to know how to align the tiles and the pixels when you already have a raster coverage you want everything to be aligned on. If you don't already have a raster coverage you can use the other variant of ST_AsRaster() to parameter the alignment. Your problem is definitely alignment...