# postgis vector raster not being displayed error

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql

postgis 2.3 postgres 9.5 64 bit windows 10.

I loaded a raster layer correctly into postgis

```
raster2pgsql.exe -s 3424 -I -C -M R:\Data\LUCZ_2017\ConservationPriorityAreas\data\rasters\abid -F -t 100x100 havdeel3 | psql -U postgres -d raster -h localhost -p 5432
```

and did a simple conversion to polygon which works correctly.

```
drop table if exists polys;
create table polys as
select st_polygon(rast)::geometry(multipolygon,3424) geom from havdeel3;

ALTER TABLE polys ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

This vector layer gets properly displayed in QGIS.

NOW I am trying to do the simplest conversion back to raster

```
drop table if exists raster_poly;
create table raster_poly as
select id,ST_AsRaster(geom, 50,50,'4BUI') rast from polys;
```

The table correctly displays but when I try and display it in QGIS it gives me this error

```
2018-07-10T15:03:35 WARNING  : 
2018-07-10T15:04:47 CRITICAL    Layer is not valid : The layer dbname='scrap' host=localhost port=5432 user='postgres' password='--' sslmode=disable key='r_table_catalog' srid=3424 type=Polygon table="public"."raster_columns" (extent) sql= is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map. Reason: 
2018-07-10T15:05:16 WARNING  : 
2018-07-10T15:11:18 WARNING  : 
2018-07-10T15:11:25 INFO     : Connection to scrap was successful.
2018-07-10T15:12:37 WARNING  : 
2018-07-10T15:13:41 WARNING  : 
2018-07-10T15:17:27 WARNING  : 
2018-07-10T15:20:58 WARNING  :
```

I have seen this tutorial http://geospatialelucubrations.blogspot.com/2014/05/a-guide-to-rasterization-of-vector.html but it is not so helpful.

[image]

Seems to be a similar question to this [List of vector to one raster in PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115130/list-of-vector-to-one-raster-in-postgis) which was never answered.

I also have tried the answer to this question with my problem and I still get the same error [ST_AsRaster for polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198419/st-asraster-for-polygon)

Reworked query that doesn't work

```
select id,ST_AsRaster(st_transform(geom,3424), 100,100,ARRAY['8BUI'], 
                  ARRAY[118]) rast from polys
```

or this doesn't work either

```
select id,ST_AsRaster(st_buffer(geom,0), 100,100,ARRAY['8BUI'], 
                  ARRAY[118]) rast from polys
```

But how does this work?

```
SELECT ST_AsRaster(ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-30 40, -20 30, -25 20, -23 10, -30 40))', 4326), 50),100,100,ARRAY['8BUI'],ARRAY[118]);
```

Comment: What if you do SELECT DISTINCT ST_SRID(ST_AsRaster(geom, 50,50,'4BUI')) FROM polys; How many different SRID do you get?

Comment: I think the error message is misleading. It's probably not a problem of SRID but a problem of alignment. You must use the other variant of ST_AsRaster() to make sure all rasters are all aligned identically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I do not know why this worked but I used st_dump to break down the vector multipolygons and the conversion back to raster worked and I am able to display it in QGIS

```
drop table if exists polys;
create table polys as
with poly as(select st_polygon(rast)::geometry(multipolygon,3424) geom 
        from havdeel3
        )
select (st_dump(geom)).geom geom from poly;

ALTER TABLE polys ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;

drop table if exists raster_poly;
create table raster_poly as
select id,ST_AsRaster(geom, 100,100,ARRAY['8BUI'], 
                  ARRAY[118]) rast from polys;
```

However, the raster does not perfectly match up with the vector layer polys it was formed from, which is something I will ask in a new question